# Cynicism: Is one usage-sense close to pessimism?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I think I have come across uses of cynicism in modern contexts where it seems close to pessimism. The dictionary definitions available are pointing towards **cynics** being ones who make judgements on peoples' motivations; but then there are usage guides out there that are making much closer comparisons with how **pessimism** is used, namely a certain kind of judgement about life or circumstances in general.

So should cynicism only be used in terms of a view on people's motivations (namely, that they are guided by self interest or mal-intent)? Or can I say something like: the recent economic and security situation has made me cynical about this country's future?

Comment: Merriam-Webster says in its definition of "cynical": "contemptuously distrustful of human nature and motives", so it's not solely about motivations, at least according to them. Having said that, there's definitely a human component to cynicism: you could be pessimistic about the chances of the Earth being destroyed by an asteroid, but not cynical. This is largely based on intuition, though.

Comment: And just as with the modern sense of *stoicism* has little to do with the Stoics for which is it is named, modern *cynicism* has very little to do with the Cynics for which it is named.

Comment: I don't know why I'm doing this. For one, I did get an answer that I think explains what my query was about. But another Q got closed here. The Q was not asking responders to pull things from the dictionary. It was wondering if the usage of cynicism has morphed over time into something resembling pessimism. The comments and alephzero's answer confirm that for me, and explain why I have been observing use cases for this word that are not directly referencing human nature. Anyway, what the heck I guess this is all just useless whining probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental meaning of "cynicism" is "the belief that people are only motivated by self interest".

For a cynic, it therefore follows that "if some plan or idea is *not* motivated by self interest, then it will not be carried out".

Your sentence "the recent economic and security situation has made me cynical about this country's future" is fine. It means "I think the future of this country would be better if its leaders did not act in their own self interest, but I don't believe that will happen."